# using attributes vs conventional getting properties

Tags: c#, reflection, conventions

I need to find all properties of a specific object which are not readonly and based on their type do something 
I mean if the type of property is int i need to do sth and if it is string i should do something else

using reflection and get this type and conventionally i can create an object which can do what I want
for example if the property type is Int , I can create an instance of IntType:IType class

but I have another option: set an attribute for each property and based on these attributes,find suitable IType
I just cant decide which one is better?

Comment: What is `sth`? And what's with the `,,`?

Comment: I think sth means 'something'. Grrr, I hate abbreviation where there is no real saving in saying/ writing it!

Comment: @Oded: I guess `sth` is shortcut for `something`

Comment: @Jalal: I'm sure it is - and I suspect Oded realized this too, and was merely commenting on the laziness of the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the information you need is already contained in the type of the property, I can't see how introducing a new attribute is a good idea. Aside from anything else, you can easily forget to update the attribute when the data type changes. You start off with:

```
[Int32Type]
int Foo { get; set; }
```

then find you actually need it to be a `long`, but forget to change the attribute:

```
[Int32Type]
long Foo { get; set; }
```

Now you're probably going to be acting incorrectly on it.

If you're *really* adding information - e.g. if not *all* `int` properties need to be treated the same way - that's a different matter.

Comment: so you mean that if i kinda have to do different stuff in int types, based on some conditions, its better to have attributes? Am I right?

Comment: @Adrakadabra: Not just better, but *necessary*. That should be the test: does your type indicate everything you need to know? If so, don't introduce redundancy with an attribute. If not, attributes provide a simple way of adding that extra information.